# How to efficiently determine video duration on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, video

I'm building a web page that needs to show multiple videos in a grid. Next to each video I need to display its duration.

I understand that in order to determine a video's duration I need to use the [`duration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/duration) property.

Initially the `duration` property on a video element is `NaN`, so I have therefore added an event listener so I can wait for the [`durationchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/durationchange_event) event to be fired.

According to [Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#preload), setting the `preload` attribute to `metadata` 'indicates that only video metadata (e.g. length) is fetched', although they go on to stress that this property is a mere hint.

On Chrome, setting `preload` to `metadata` on each video element results in a small chunk of the video being fetched, and the `durationchange` event being fired in a timely fashion.

On Firefox however, when `preload` is set to `metadata`, a significant chunk of the video (or sometimes seemingly all of the video) is fetched, meaning it can sometimes be many seconds before the `durationchange` event is fired (sometimes minutes (!) if the video is large, and there are many videos to display on the page).

I have prepared a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/robbing779/7gx1beao/75/) to illustrate this. You will notice that on Firefox the videos and their respective durations take a long time to appear.

Here are developer tools screenshots of Chrome fetching the media:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

and then Firefox:

[image: Firefox screenshot]

As you can see, Firefox is fetching approximately 20 times as much data for each video.

I understand that the Firefox team have in the past [argued that fetching more video data is a feature rather than a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=937148#c9), but **what can I do to quickly determine the duration of a video**, especially if there are lots of large videos to display on a page at once? I don't want to wait 10+secs to be able to show these video durations.

As per the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/robbing779/7gx1beao/75/) example, I have also experimented with other events like `loadedmetadata`, but they also take a longer time on Firefox to be triggered.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know if there's server-side code involved in your project. But one thing would be to determine the video duration on server-side and send the url, alongside with the duration, via JSON to your frontend. In addition, the JSON could then be cached so your server doesn't have to do it every time again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AlexBerger. Figuring this out server-side is indeed an option, I was just wondering if there was a way to leverage existing browser functionality without building something separate.